# Google chrome not accepting any security certificates

Tags: google-chrome, security, certificate

I've recently developed a problem with Google Chrome that's really annoying. I'm using Firefox at the moment with no problems whatsoever and it's the same with IE, so it's safe to say this problem is specific to Chrome. The problem is that it's not accepting security certificates from certain sites.

I suppose the best place to start would be google itself. I can't search. The google search page will load but when I type some search term into the search box and hit 'search' I get the message:

"*You attempted to reach www.google.com, but the server presented an invalid certificate. You cannot proceed because the website operator has requested heightened security for this domain.*"

No matter what the search term is, this is the result. Also when I try to log in to facebook - same message. Youtube works and many other sites that I know present security certs so I'm baffled. I've searched and there are other people who have had *similar* issues but I can't find a solution anywhere. The most common answer I'm picking up for this is to "check your system time" but I can safely say that it's not my system time.

If anyone knows what is going on, I'd very much appreciate being informed. It's not super urgent as I can use Firefox to access those places Chrome won't, but it IS super annoying because I can usually sort out issues like this in no time.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility of seeing security certificate errors is because your local machine's **time** is out of sync. Update your system date/time to solve the problem.

Comment: And most likely you are off by *years*.

Comment: That wouldn't generally be the case when you can still use firefox, however when both are giving the same problem then it's most likely that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that Chrome was recently hit with a bug that is causing this issue.

http://www.slashgear.com/google-chrome-hit-by-ssl-bug-restricting-google-services-06221921/

and

http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/yHclY2CexIE

seem to confirm this.  The issue appears to be with the latest version of Chrome running on Windows 7 64-bit.

Edit:

From here: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=118706

> It appears that if i delete "chrome_shutdown_ms.txt" from the User Data folder then all websites open correctly (gmail, etc).  However, the problem reappears upon restarting the browser since the file is recreated on exit.

Comment: Thanks - that's a good stop-gap solution there. Would point out that in order to see the file "chrome_shutdown_ms.txt you first have to close chrome. Delete it and restart chrome for normal browsing ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can get rid of this problem by clearing all browsing data.

1. Go to Settings > Under the Hood > Clear Browsing Data
2. For "Obliterate the following items from", select: "The beginning of time"
3. Select all items because you don't know which certificate caused the crash.
4. Click "Clear browsing data".

This will clear all passwords, history, bookmarks, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows just go to control panel, click on automatic updates then click on Windows Update Web Site link. Just follow the step. At least this works for me, no more certificates issue i.e whenever I go to https://www.dropbox.com as before.